# how to implement business and bar code scanning in windows 8?

Tags: barcode

Can any one respond if there is any free lib for businesscard scanning and bar code scanning for Windows 8 which does the OCR functionality locally without depending on any webservices?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try BarcodeScanner class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.aspx
There is also a possibility to use HTML 5 for this, here is the example: http://www.webqr.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)